# How to find where size is coming from in Flash's Bandwidth Profiler?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader

I'm working on a Flash CS5/AS3 pre loader, and the bandwidth profiler is telling me that my frame 1 size is massive - about 850kb. Frame 2 is 128kb. This results in a white screen during the bulk of loading, followed by the brief and now-unecessary preloader, and then the rest of the swf.

I have a setup of two frames, the first being the preloader with the following code:

```
stop();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, preLoad)

function preLoad(event:Event):void{
var bytestoLoad:Number = loaderInfo.bytesTotal;
var numberLoaded:Number = loaderInfo.bytesLoaded;
if (bytestoLoad == numberLoaded){
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, preLoad)
    gotoAndStop(2);
} else {
    preLoaderInst.preLoaderFill.scaleX = numberLoaded/bytestoLoad;
    preLoaderInst.bytesPercent.text = Math.floor(numberLoaded/bytestoLoad*100) + "%";
}
}
```

Frame 2 just has: 
    `stop();`

The .as file associated with the fla has tons of other information, a full game.  Let me know if more detail here is helpful.

I've already gone through my library and on all the symbols with Linkage, unchecked the "Export in Frame 1".  Also the pre-loader is small, only a text box and a shape.

How can I get more detail of it's loading in frame 1 so that I can move it to frame 2?  Thanks so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I've no clue about your fla file, but if there is objects that exported for AS in your library. They have a property "Export in frame 1". This will make all of your objects to load at first frame.

Hope it helps, i prefer to make another swf file that loads main into it. This will solve your problems. Unchecking "Export in frame 1" will not help you much. 
your way sounds like activeden preloaders that not the best way.

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the first frame empty, just add the preloader item in it.

In the library, check all the symbols that are exported for actionscript. You must uncheck the "export in first frame" checkbox.

At this point your symbols are not exported at all in the swf except if you put them somewhere on the stage.

My advice is to put one instance of each symbol on frame 2 and skip this frame by jumping directly to frame 3 in your loader : gotoAndStop(3);

As adviced, you should consider using another swf for loading the main swf.